# Serilog Filter Expression is not working to exclude the given endpoint logs

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I've a healthcheck endpoint in my .NetCore(2.2) WebAPI project for which I don't want to generate and write any logs. I'm writing the logs to WindowsEventLog. For that, I'm using a separate config file just for the logging purpose which I'm loading in my startup.

This is the endpoint that I've in the controller for healthcheck:

```
[Route("healthcheck")] 
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Ok("");
}
```

This is how I'm loading the config file (SeriLogSettings.json) that I created for holding my Serilog configuration:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
               .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
               .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
               .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
               .AddJsonFile("SeriLogSettings.json", optional: false)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

And this is how my SerilogSettings.json looks like:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Settings.Configuration", "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" ],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '%/healthcheck')"
        }
      }
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "EventLog",
        "Args": {
          "source": "WebAPI", 
          "logName": "Application",
          "managedEventSource": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "ApplicationAPI"
    }
  }
}
```

Despite using the ByExcluding expression to exclude the logs for /healthcheck endpoint, I'm getting the logs in the WindowsEventLog.
I'm not able to fix why this is happening and not sure what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `%` character in the path you're checking, it should just be `/healthcheck`.

```
"expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck')"
```

If you take a look at [the documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions/blob/dev/README.md) on the GitHub page, you'll see they also just mention `/SomeEndpoint` when testing the request path.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried and it didn't work. I even tried this expression but still didn't work:
"expression": "RequestPath like '%/healthcheck%'"

Comment: Also ensure that you have the correct filter NuGet installed
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Filters.Expressions/

Comment: Serilog.Filters.Expressions is deprecated and will be replaced by Serilog.Expressions. Config settings stay the same.

Comment: Is there a known limitation on only allowing a single exclusion filter, or are multiple filters of the same type allowed? I've not been able to get multiples to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

1. may be simple -
   "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck')" should become
   "StartsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck')"
   Because your requst may by
   /healthcheck/live, /healthcheck/ready
2. Or more puzzle situation
   You did not show packages for your project.
   Maybe you are using package Serilog.Expressions instead of package Serilog.**Filters**.Expressions(deprecated)

Those packages use different formats for string 'expression'

```
Old
"expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/healthcheck')"
New
"expression": "RequestPath like '/healthcheck%')"
```

[The documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions)